# Программное удаление файлов C++

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить (переместить или скопировать) файл из программы. Притом надо, чтобы можно было не только внутри директории, а и в другие папки.  На сей раз своего варианта нет. Вариант `system();` не предлагать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

переименование/перемещение файла -

```
rename(char * old_name, char * new_name)
```

Это стандартная функция cstdio. Для низкоуровневого программирования нужно использовать сочетание link()-unlink().

Стандартная библиотечная функция удаления файла - remove(char * file_name)

Для копирования что-то не припомню ничего, кроме open() - write() - close()

Answer (score 4):

[unlink()](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_280.html) !?

Comment: спасибо. когда искал вынтернете нашел всякий мусор схожий с программами на brainfuck.